# Trouble install PIP Windows

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I have read posts on here but something doesn't seem to work. I am new to `Python dev`. I am running `windows 7 64bit`.

I am trying to install `pip` which I have downloaded and have `easy_install` in my `c:\python27\scripts` directory. When I use `powershell` and type

```
"python easy_install pip"
```

I get the error message:

> "can't open file easy_install": [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

This seems odd as I can see the `easy_install.exe` is in that directory.

I have added `c:\python27\scripts` to my `system PATH` but, to be honest, I am not sure if this is right.

Could someone please help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to fix this is to compile `easy_install` yourself. First download the source code, and then compile it using python.

1 - Go [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

[image]

2 - Then extract the file, using 7-zip, or any software that can unzip a tar file. This is a `tar.gz` file, so after one extraction, it will give you the `tar` file, and then it will give you the actual directory and files for setup tools

3 - Go into the directory where you stored the contents of the extraction (using command prompt). For example, if you stored the directory on your desktop, you `cd Desktop` and then you go

`cd dir_where_easy_install_is`.

4 - Then run this command `python setup.py install`

That will install `easy_install` for you.

5 - Go back to your command line again, and then just type in `easy_install pip`, and that will install pip.

Then go ahead, and test it out, by installing django, just go into your command prompt, and enter this `pip install django`. After the download and the install, type in `pip list`, and see if django is in there. If it is, then pip has been successfully installed.

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer dint fix it

This did:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked running python from it's main dir against the easy_install.py in the extracted setuptools directory.

[image]

Then pip files should be in the Scripts dir.

[image]

Don't forget to run your CMD as administrator.